# Chrome browser infinitely console logging MessageEvent

Tags: google-chrome, events, google-chrome-console, browser-console

I've noticed my chrome browser automatically logging the MessageEvent object and it's disrupting my app development.

Originally, I thought the problem was from my code but I just noticed that even when visiting [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) or any website at all, It still logs the MessageEvent object. I searched through chrome settings and couldn't find any option labeled "Message Event"; I don't know what to do anymore.